# what is the maximum size of JsonResult in mvc Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have to work on the MVC with angular based application, I have to retrieve 20000 thousand data from a database to send with Angular.

If I send below of 13000 data return from json, its returning error.
else getting this error.

So  have used the below solution, it works fine, But why have to use this  , what is the limited size of JSON result.

```
  var jsonResult = Json(x, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
                    return jsonResult;
```

what is the maximum size of JsonResult it is in data size ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your error disappear if you write it in a bit another way:

```
return new JsonResult()
{
    Data = x,
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
    MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
};
```

Comment: I have already used this to solve the problem , I need to know why we use this or what is the max size of default jsonresult ?If there is any limitations there

Comment: @MohamedSahir i gess you should just check mvc sources for this questin. It's open source you can find it on github

Comment: Bur i can gess that you having this error becouse you try to serialize your data before you set max lenght. You basically get default  maxlength value. You can change default value in web.config if you want to solve this issue in entier project.